# list child-pages as normal pages?

Tags: pages, page-specific-settings

```
wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=&exclude=');
```

lists all pages of my site. If there are childpages of a certain page the output looks like this:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-2">
    <a href="http://domain.com/about" title="About">About</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-29">
            <a href="http://domain.com/about/subpage" title="Subpage">Subpage</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li class="page_item page-item-39"><a href="http://domain.com/about/subpage/subsub" title="SubSub">SubSub</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Is there a simple trick to print childpages without seperate 's so that the output looks like this:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-2">
    <a href="http://domain.com/about" title="About">About</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-29">
    <a href="http://domain.com/about/subpage" title="Subpage">Subpage</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-39"><a href="http://domain.com/about/subpage/subsub" title="SubSub">SubSub</a>
</li>
```

I need that version just for a specific part of my page so it shouldn't be a filter that is added to wp_list_pages().

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [**get_pages()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) function, something like this:

```
$mypages = get_pages();
echo '<ul>';
foreach($mypages as $page){     
    echo '<li class="page_item page-item-'.$page->ID.'"><a href="'.get_page_link($page->ID).'">'.$page->post_title.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I believe that passing `depth=-1` to **wp_list_pages()** should list all pages as a flat, non-nested list. It won't preserve the order of sub-pages, though, so you're not guaranteed that "Subpage" will immediately follow "About" in your example... Everything will be ordered by the field selected in the `sort_column` parameter.

Comment: Indeed you are correct! I had forgotten about that. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Answer (score 0):

Not by default. wp_list_pages() does not have a "hierarchical" argument. It will always output Pages as hierarchical.

You could modify the CSS, such that the child ULs and LIs appear identical to the parent ULs/LIs, but the pages will still be listed hierarchically.